# How do I use a node.js cli tool from within an angular application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I stumbled upon this node.js cli tool that verifies two .json files against each other:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-mock-validator

Now to use it, you have to install it via npm and execute it through cli commands.

I want to set up an angular application in which I can use this validation tool (without needing a command line terminal).

Is this possible? If so, how? Do I have to rewrite the whole thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot call native applications from front-end code. You'll need to create a server that calls the CLIs and then have your front-end communicate with it over HTTP/REST.

Comment: Okay, so can I write a script that uses this tool on the server side without using the command line? Or do I have to tell my server to open a cl, execute the commands, read the output on the cl and send it to the client via REST?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the tool you linked doesn't have a Node API, so I think you'd have to have your server spawn a child process and read the result from stdout, unfortunately. If you decide to go that route and you're using Node for your server, look into the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) module as a starting point. Basically every language has something similar, though.

Comment: I already looked into `child_process` but it is just such an ugly workaround. Looks like it will have to do, though. Thank you for the confirmation @JoeClay!